# Why can't I connect to my web server using IPv6 although the port is open?

Tags: linux, lighttpd

I am running a Lighttpd web server on my Raspberry Pi. Since this question isn't Pi related I thought it would better fit in here. I am using IPv6 to connect to the web server on port 8080 and it is working fine. However as soon as I try to connect from the outside world the connection is refused.

I have set a port forwarding in my router settings. When I use `tcpdump port 8080` and then go to [Ipv6scanner.com](http://www.ipv6scanner.com/) I can see in the logs that there are packets being received and that the port is open according to Ipv6scanner.

[image: Listening to port 8080: packets are received]

However trying to access the IPv6 in the browser will always result in a refused connection.

What could be the reason and what would be the next steps for me to find out whether it is a problem with the server or the router? Am I right that the fact that the port is reachable tells me that the router is correctly forwarding the port and that it shouldn't be a firewall problem from the router?

Comment: Using curl like so `curl -g -6 http://[1234:4567:145f:2353:945c:1453:4701:1234]:8080/test.h‌​tml` I can access the contents of my IPv6 server even when using a completely different Wifi. So it seems `curl` works but the browser doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: the WIFI I used to test is a public one which doesn't seem to support IPv6. I also tested on my phone using LTE and it didn't work there either. But as I found out Vodafone doesn't support IPv6 yet in Germany so that was the reason.